# iTunes is not reflecting my uploaded IPA built in Visual Studio

Tags: ios, iphone, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017

I want to add my first iOS application developed with Visual Studio 2017 Xamarin iOS. I created the new version for my app in the iTunes Connect, filled up all the information required. Then I went to the application loader to upload it and the process done successfully, but in the iTunes Connect no build appear. I reviewed my email and it said:

> "Dear developer,   We have discovered one or more issues with your
>   recent delivery for "E2EWorks Mobile". To process your delivery, the
>   following issues must be corrected:  Missing Info.plist value - A
>   value for the Info.plist key 'CFBundleIconName' is missing in the
>   bundle 'com.e2eworks.e2eworksmobile'. Apps built with iOS 11 or later
>   SDK must supply app icons in an asset catalog and must also provide a
>   value for this Info.plist key. For more information see
>   http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev10510b1f7.   Once these
>   issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected
>   binary.  Regards, The App Store team"

I fixed all necessary things and rebuild application again but now application loader doesn't let me to upload again. I checked iTunes activity but no application is shown however submmit to review button is enabled. Under builds section it keeps saying: "Submit your builds using Xcode 6.0 or later, or Application Loader 3.0 or later."
 
Please your help.

Answer (score 0):

Every upload of IPA's bundle to iTunes Connect requieres a unique and distinct CFBundleVersion string on info.plist, so any issue caused just after uploaded or rejected event that must be corrected, a new CFBundleVersion must be set. In my case it started with 1.0 and after correction, string changed to 1.0.1 (minor bugs fixed) and proceeded to build and uploaded again succesfully. I'm newbie in iOS stuffs.

I hope this help to anyone in similar situation!